# Problem creating Array of References to DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use this hook : react-use-scrollspy that uses an sectionRefs of useRef in array

```
 const sectionRefs = [
    useRef(null),
    useRef(null),
    useRef(null),
  ];

  const activeSection = useScrollSpy({
    sectionElementRefs: sectionRefs,
    offsetPx: -80,
  });
```

But I use this instead of that array of refs :

```
const menuItemsRef = {
        home: "0",
        packs: "4",
        faq : "8",
        projects: "2",            
        team : "7",
        contact : "6"    
    }
    const menuRef = useRef(Object.keys(menuItemsRef));
    let menuRef2 = [];    
    useEffect(()=>{
        menuRef2 = Object.values(menuRef.current).slice(6,12).map((item)=>
        {
            return { current : item }
        });
        console.log("menuRef " , menuRef2);
    },[]);
    const activeSectionNavbar = useScrollSpy({
        sectionElementRefs: menuRef2,
        offsetPx: -80,
    });
```

Why it didn't work?

To clarify , my problem is to turn this :

```
const menuItemsRef = {
        home: "0",
        packs: "4",
        faq : "8",
        projects: "2",            
        team : "7",
        contact : "6"    
    }
    const menuRef = useRef(Object.keys(menuItemsRef));
```

in this :

```
 const sectionRefs = [
    useRef(null),
    useRef(null),
    useRef(null),
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing creates a ref that contains an array

```js
useRef(Object.keys(menuItemsRef))
// { current: [...] }
```

What your hook seems to expect is an array that contains refs

```js
const sectionRefs = [
    useRef(null),
    useRef(null),
    useRef(null),
];
// [ { current: ... }, { current: ... }, { current: ... } ]
```

What you need to do is to keep the "properties" of a react *ref* (the fact that its content persists across renders) while giving it a structure that matches what your hook is expecting:

```js
const refArray = useRef(Object.values(menuItemsRef).map(value => ({current: value})))
// { current: [ { current: ... }, { current: ... }, { current: ... } ] }

const activeSectionNavbar = useScrollSpy({
  sectionElementRefs: refArray.current,
  offsetPx: -80,
});
```

Comment: Still dosent work, and if I put a console.log("refArray " , refArray.current) , I have this return : 
`
refArray  
(6) […]
​
0: Object { current: "0" }
​
1: Object { current: "4" }
​
2: Object { current: "8" }
​
3: Object { current: "2" }
​
4: Object { current: "7" }
​
5: Object { current: "6" }
​
contact: <div>
​
faq: <div>
​
home: <div>
​
length: 6
​
packs: <div>
​
projects: <div>
​
team: <div>
​
<prototype>: Array []
App.js:47

`

*Ps: Other functions like ScrollTo(*ref) work

Comment: @Athos looks like `menuItemsRef` is polluted by something else, it isn't purely the object you depicted in your `const` declaration.

Comment: is this right? : `<div ref={  r => refArray.current['projects'] = r }> <ProjectsApp /> </div>`